# How to remove Ubuntu 14.04.03 Grub password protection?

Tags: grub2

Ubuntu 14.04.03 server  has Grub protection password which is difficult to manage in case of every reboot.

Server has Grub protection password which is difficult to manage in case of every reboot.

Please let me know the procedure how we can remove that GRUB Password protection or bypass it.Please suggest us the work around to fix the issue.

Answer (score 5):

You should first find where the password has been set. A `grep` in `/etc/grub.d` may help.

Then just comment the line starting with `set superusers` and the line with the `password` and run `update-grub`.

That should do it (if still relevant).